# Run spring project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am new in spring.I imported one spring project in eclipse and try to run with apache tomcat but it is not running.There is no main method in project.It contains only controllers and models and one jsp page.
[image]
When i tried to run  as a java application is shows below dialog. Please help me.I tried all in google for how to run spring project but i can't understand.Please tell me how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have added tomcat to your eclipse.
If your project is pure java project then it will not show you the run on server option in eclipe. You need to change project facet and add dynamic web module to it then you can run it on tomcat server from eclipse.Basically project needs to be web project.

After doing above if it gives error or do not run properly, check your project deployment assembly and add projects webapps folder in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your rply.I have to add dynamic web module in project facet.

Answer (score 2):

you need to have a tomcat installed in your eclipse and run it on the server.

[Here is a tutorial to do this](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/j2ee/scenarios/running_webproject.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i had already installed tomcat in eclipse.i can run another web application in eclipse successfully.

Comment: so is there still a problem?

Comment: yes.Still i am not able to run spring project.I am able to run servlet and jsp's web applications but not this.

Comment: i really don't get whats wrong... simpliy run your spring applikation on server not as java application

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools), which has support for the usual Web-application tools.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i can run my servlet and jsp project with current configuration in eclipse.so is there any special configuration required for run spring project?

Comment: You said that you can already run it, but you don't launch a servlet/JSP project with "Java Application". You need to "Run on server".